# Perl regex with grouping in LHS

Tags: regex, perl

How to can match the next lines?

```
sometext_TEXT1.yyy-TEXT1.yyy
anothertext_OTHER.yyy-MAX.yyy
```

want remove the `- repetative.text` from the end, but only if it repeats.

```
sometext_TEXT1.yyy
anothertext_OTHER.yyy-MAX.yyy
```

my trying

```
use strictures;
my $text="sometext_TEXT1.xxx-TEXT1.xxx";
$text =~ s/(.*?)(.*)(\s*-\s*$2)/$1$2/;
print "$text\n";
```

prints

```
Use of uninitialized value $2 in regexp compilation at a line 3.
```

with other words, looking for better solution for the next `split + match`...

```
while(<DATA>) {
        chomp;

        my($first, $second) = split /\s*-\s*/;
        s/\s*-\s*$second$// if ( $first =~ /$second$/ );

        print "$_\n";
}
__DATA__
sometext_TEXT1.yyy-TEXT1.yyy
anothertext_OTHER.yyy-MAX.yyy
```

Comment: the backreference in the match part of the substitution needs to be \2 not $2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$text =~ s/(.*?)(.*)(\s*-\s*$2)/$1$2/;
```

This regex has various issues, but is on the right path.

1. Use `\2` (or better: `\g2` or `\g{-1}`) or something to reference the contents of a capture group. The `$2` variable is interpolated when the Perl statement is executed. At that time, `$2` is undefined, as there was no previous match. You get a warning as it is uninitialized. Even if it were defined, the pattern would be fixed during compilation.
2. You define three capture groups, but only need one. There is a trick with the `\K`eep directive: It let's the regex engine forget the previously matched text, so that it won't be affected by the substitution. That is, `s/(foo)b/$1/` is equivalent to `s/foo\Kb//`. The effect is similar to a variable-length lookbehind.
3. The `(.*?)(.*)` part is a bit of an backtracking nightmare. We can reduce the cost of your match by adding further conditions, e.g. by anchoring the pattern at start and end of line. Using above modifications, we now have `s/^.*?(.*)\K\s*-\s*\g1$//`. But on second thought, we can just remove the `^.*?` because this describes something the regex engine does anyway!

A short test:

```
while(<DATA>) {
  s/(.*)\K\s*-\s*\g1$//;
  print;
}
__DATA__
sometext_TEXT1.yyy-TEXT1.yyy
anothertext_OTHER.yyy-MAX.yyy
```

Output:

```
sometext_TEXT1.yyy
anothertext_OTHER.yyy-MAX.yyy
```

---

A few words regarding your `split`ting solution: This will also shorten the line

```
sometext_TEXT1xyyy - 1.xyyy
```

because when you interpolate a variable into a regex, the contents aren't matched literally. Instead, they are interpreted as a pattern (where `.` matches any non-newline codepoint)! You can avoid this by quoting all metacharacters with the `\Q...\E` escape:

```
s/\s*-\s*\Q$second\E$// if $first =~ /\Q$second\E$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$2` Perl will try to interpolate that variable, but the variable will only be set *after* the match has completed. What you want, is a backreference, for which you need to use `\2`:

```
$text =~ s/(.*?)(.*)(\s*-\s*\2)/$1$2/;
```

Note that, when the replacement part is evaluated, `$1` and `$2` have been set and can be interpolated as expected. Also you could make the pattern a bit more concise (and probably more efficient), by using:

```
$text =~ s/(.*)\s*-\s*\2/$1/;
```

There is no need to match the initial part (`.*?`) if it's arbitrary and you just write it back anyway. What you might want to do though, is anchor the pattern to the end of the string:

```
$text =~ s/(.*)\s*-\s*\1$/$1/;
```

Otherwise (with your initial attempt or mine), you'd turn `something-thingelse` into `somethingelse`.

Comment: the last regex should be `$text =~ s/(.*)\s*-\s*\1$/$1/;`... :)